# Cannot require two classes in php

Tags: php, include, require

I am currently working on a little website and i am trying to require two classes. When I only require one class, everything works fine but when I require two classes my page is not working any more.

**This code works:**

```
<?php
require '../assets/php/mapManager.php';

$mapManager = new mapManager();
?>
```

**This code works:**

```
<?php
require '../assets/php/accountManager.php';

$accountManager = new accountManager();
?>
```

**This code works not:**

```
<?php
require '../assets/php/mapManager.php';
require '../assets/php/accountManager.php';

$mapManager = new mapManager();
$accountManager = new accountManager();
?>
```

Comment: So what happens when you require two files?

Comment: No reason why that should not work, so you had better show us whats inside both those included files

Comment: Have you got error reporting turned on? If not turn it on and it should at least give you some clues

Comment: Can you provide the errors you are seeing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My hypothesis is that each of those class files includes or requires the same file containing a parent `Manager` class or some other common dependency, and you're getting a fatal error when you try to redeclare the class in that file. You can fix this by using `require_once` instead of `require`, or ideally by implementing autoloading.

Normally I wouldn't post a "guess" answer, but based on the context and naming and the way the error is occurring I think this is *extremely* likely, and if it doesn't happen to be the problem in your case, it definitely will be for someone else with the same question.

Comment: Thank you, both my "manager" classes required the "config.php" class. I changed it into "require_once" and it works.

Comment: You're welcome! I do recommend that you look into using autoloading. It may seem like overkill for a small project, but it makes it so much easier to work on and really isn't difficult to set up.